# Wix burn does not show multiple entries in ARP

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.7, addremoveprograms

I use Wix 3.7's burn to install prereq's (Windows Installer 4.5, .NET 3.5, SQL Server 2008 R2 and Sync Framework 2.1) prior to the installation of my two product MSI's.

Even though all of the prereqs' have entries in Add or Remove Programs (ARP), the ARP entries for my product specific MSI's are not there.  There is only one entry, and that is of the bootstrapper.

Is there a way to display only the entries for my product MSI's instead of the bootstrapper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your bundle needs to be registered in ARP so the user can uninstall it and clean up the package cache that Burn maintains. You can also show your MSIs in ARP if you want by setting the packages' Visible attributes to "yes".

Comment: so if the user were to perform a manual uninstall of my products MSI's through ARP and then use the bootstrapped exe to install the new version, could that cause problems due to the burn cache?

Comment: If the new bundle is an upgrade of the old one, the new bundle will uninstall the old one, which will clean up the package cache.

Comment: Thanks @BobArnson!  The MsiPackage/@Visible="yes" worked beautifully!